# How can I navigate directly to news article by pasting a URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I paste the URL of the news details directly, without opening news component, it shows me blank screen - and from there I have to navigate news to news_details.

I want when i open news_detail without navigating from news, so news details show me the data which i want.

news component

```
import React from 'react'
import './News.css'
import { BsCalendarDate } from 'react-icons/bs'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { NewscolRef } from '../../Firebase'


const News = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();


    const News_Details = (id) => {
        navigate("News_Details", {
            state: {
                id: id,
                N_Info: getNewsInfo,
            },
        })
    }



    const [getNewsInfo, setNewsInfo] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getDocs(NewscolRef)
            .then((snapshot) => {
                let NewsInfo = []
                snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                    NewsInfo.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
                    setNewsInfo(NewsInfo)
                })
            }).catch((err) => console.log(err + "Error"))
    }, [])






    return (

        <>
            <h1 className='News_Heading'>News</h1>

            <section id='news'>





                {
                    getNewsInfo.map((news, id) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={id} className='news_card'>

                                <img src={news.img} alt='' />

                                <h1 onClick={() => {
                                    News_Details(id)
                                }}>
                                    {news.news}
                                </h1>

                                <div className='news_card_date_div'>
                                    <BsCalendarDate className='icon' />
                                    <p >
                                        {news.date}
                                    </p>
                                </div>


                            </div>

                        )
                    })
                }




            </section>
        </>
    )
}

export default News;
```

news_Details component

```
import React from "react";
import './News_Details.css';
import { BsCalendarDate } from 'react-icons/bs'

// import er from './image/1.jpeg';
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";


function News_Details() {

    const loaction = useLocation();
    const index = loaction.state.id
    React.useEffect(() => {


    }, [])

    console.log("News is ", loaction.state.N_Info)
    return (
        <>
            <section className="News_Details_Section">


                <div className="top">
                    <h1>{loaction.state.N_Info[index].news}</h1>
                </div>
                <hr></hr>
                <div className="back">
                    <div className="Nwes_Details_Date">
                        <BsCalendarDate />
                        <h2>{loaction.state.N_Info[index].date}</h2>
                    </div>

                    <aside className="newa_img_d">                   <div className="para">

                        <p align="justify">{loaction.state.N_Info[index].discription}</p>
                    </div>
                        <div className="im">
                            <img className="News_Detalis_Imgae" src={loaction.state.N_Info[index].img} alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </section>
        </>

    )

}

export default News_Details;
```

i wnt to access news details via url